# Extension not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, krl

I'm having a hard time getting my installed extension to work in IE 8. When i run it through a bookmarklet everything loads correctly and the extension works as intended. When installing the extension it won't run automatically on the pages it should.

Currently it'll only work on www.bestbuy.com. Also the click-through won't work, but you should be able to tell if the extension loads on those pages.

Here is the bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:(function(){var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script');s.text="KOBJ_config={'a1229x4:kynetx_app_version':'dev','rids':['a1229x4']};";d.body.appendChild(s);var l=d.createElement('script');l.src='http://init.kobj.net/js/shared/kobj-static.js';d.body.appendChild(l);})()
```

Here are links for the installers:
IE - http://app-files.s3.amazonaws.com/installers/shopscotch-qa_Setup.exe
Firefox - change to .xpi instead of .exe
Chrome - change to .crx instead of .exe

Here is the KRL code:
http://app-files.s3.amazonaws.com/installers/shopscotchKRL.js

Comment: I got the same behavior on my machine--the bookmarklet works fine but the IE extension doesn't. Not sure why, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sharing your source code. Looks like you are missing semicolons in various places in your emitted JavaScript that I'm guessing IE pukes on. I would fix that and then try again. Found on lines 107 and 111.

---

*update 02/18/2011*

Try changing your dispatch domains so that you are not including the www part of the domain. In testing I found that the IE extension doesn't like it. I have filed a bug report and hope that fixes your problem. (you don't really need the www anyway)

Previous dispatch block of

```
dispatch {
  domain "shopscotch.qat"
  domain "www.bestbuy.com"
  domain "www.bebe.com"
}
```

would become

```
dispatch {
  domain "shopscotch.qat"
  domain "bestbuy.com"
  domain "bebe.com"
}
```

After I changed the dispatch block to not have the www I was able to get it to run on bestbuy.com

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike! Sadly I tried fixing all the semi-colons in my emitted javascript but nothing comes up in IE still. I've reposted the source code here: [source](http://app-files.s3.amazonaws.com/installers/main.js). Also why would it work via the bookmarklet if semi-colons were breaking it? I have also been able to run the bookmarklet code via the console and it works fine. It seems as though the initial KRL object isn't even loading as $K on the IE console brings back undefined.

Comment: access denied on your source link

Answer (score 0):

I had similar behavior... but I cleared my cache and it started working. Not sure WTF happened, but it cleared up for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried that and unfortunately no good. I've also tried re-building the extension through the appbuilder, but that didn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: If you think the extension was built incorrectly, be sure to check force rebuild so you don't get a cached version of the extension.